# Vue - Dynamic properties from external TypeScript Class are not reactive

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a small problem, I created a package to manage forms, everything worked correctly until I needed to create a dynamic form based on an API response.

Here is the package: https://github.com/nulvem/js-form

It can be installed with npm:

```sh
npm install @nulvem/js-form
```

Here is my Vue component calling the `Form` class:

```js
<script>
import {Form} from '@nulvem/js-form'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        template: {
          value: null,
          validation: {
            rules: 'required',
            messages: {
              required: 'You must select the type of report'
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.form.template = 'random-id'

    // These data will be obtained from an API
    let fields = [
      'start_date',
      'end_date',
      'wallets',
    ]

    fields.forEach((field) => {
      let fieldData = {
        value: null,
        validation: {
          rules: 'required',
          messages: {
            required: `You must enter the field ${field.description}`
          }
        }
      }

      this.form.$addField(field, fieldData)
    })

    // Here we can only see the getter/setter of the template property that was passed when instantiating the Form class
    console.log(this.form)
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is: The fields I passed to the form during the creation of `new Form ({...})` instance are reactive, since when I add new fields by calling the `this.form.$AddField()` function the fields are not getting reactive.

The funny thing is that the `construct` of the `Form` class calls a function called `this.form.$AddFields()` that calls the `this.form.$AddField()` function several times.

Why it works inside the constructor and don't when called separated? How to fix this issue?

Any idea what might be going on? This is driving me crazy, I've been trying to find the problem for several hours and I can't find it.

### Edit

As a quick fix we make a change in the package where it is possible to pass the `Form` instance as a third parameter to the `$addFields` function, so the attributes are reactive, however we would like this to work without having to pass this parameter.

Comment: Vue 2 doesn't detect the addition/deletion of object properties, so you have to use `Vue.set()`/`Vue.delete()` for that. If you're only initializing the form in `mounted()` with all the fields from the API, I would set `form = new Form()` in `mounted()` once you have all the fields available. Then you wouldn't need to pass the context.

Comment: You have to replace the `form` instance with a new one, containing the fields. I'd argue the simplest way is to just place a `null` placeholder in `data: () => { form: null }` and set the form class instance when you have all the fields from the API. What Vue reactivity means is: all properties are replaced with getters/setters, but this only happens at top level, not for each individual nested prop. Unless you replace `form` Vue won't know about the change. And `Vue.set()` does exactly that. It replaces the instance in the prop.

Answer (score 0):

VueJS lose the reactivity of properties that are added to your `data` after the render. You can read more about this, here: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html.

A quick way to try to solve this problem is adding a `this.$forceUpdate()` everytime that you add a new property, but it also can bring another problems depending of your context.

Or you can try using `Vue.set()` method, instead of your `$addField` method. You can read more in the same link above.

Comment: I need to call `$addField()` because it will resolve my validations rules and messages inside the class

Comment: Anyway , I think you can try using `Vue.set`  and also add the properties to your `form`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the context and change this line for reactivity:

```
this.$initialValues[field] = fieldDeclaration.value;
```

=>>>

```
this.$initialValues[field] = fieldDeclaration.value;
this.$initialValues = Object.assign({}, this.$initialValues);
```

Comment: $initialValus is reactive, the problem is accessing the itens in the Form instance